# How do I import a GeoJSON MultiLineString object into SQL Server using Well Known Text?

Tags: sql-server, geojson

I am trying to import a geographical object into SQL server from a GeoJSON file. So far i've managed to import all types of object into my database except for MultiLineString objects. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to select the MultiLineString coordinates and format them to WKT/WKB in SQL. Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to turn the coordinates field for a MultiLineString object into WKT/WKB?

The GeoJSON I am trying to get into SQL Server as a geographical object:

```
{
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 2933,
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiLineString",
                "coordinates": [[[4.16252497624196, 51.9599559697169], [4.16250512611226, 51.9599336940941], [4.16248629341819, 51.9599163120517], [4.16247030578138, 51.959905582942], [4.16245103809199, 51.9598943785567], [4.16244058392407, 51.959889417422], [4.16242792404871, 51.9598850960854], [4.1624045185786, 51.9598801141883], [4.16237999301355, 51.9598760840513]], [[4.15503507430718, 51.9552020278472], [4.15503504541758, 51.9552020451014], [4.15497653185823, 51.9552331549972], [4.15495789208469, 51.9552412662596], [4.15492130124477, 51.955259183643], [4.15490660841608, 51.9552661050834], [4.15489312638887, 51.955271230856], [4.15487825658442, 51.9552765769071], [4.15486234378716, 51.9552805820963], [4.15484699083588, 51.9552823085672], [4.15482915237691, 51.9552819328935], [4.15480932384494, 51.9552801691232], [4.15479152891578, 51.9552770440607], [4.15477618484405, 51.95527314365], [4.15476227180306, 51.9552675771678], [4.15474960313705, 51.9552610624885], [4.15473547613581, 51.9552535866496], [4.15467434779864, 51.9552184819205], [4.15465604925507, 51.9552097684855], [4.15462041748137, 51.9551913378175], [4.15460489094118, 51.9551845122586], [4.15458628165371, 51.9551787077956], [4.15456985263646, 51.9551756431029], [4.15455415674036, 51.95517459635], [4.1545407635413, 51.9551758407583], [4.15452413231887, 51.9551796211054], [4.15450669285507, 51.9551852825323], [4.15446953916757, 51.9551989868194], [4.15445428734141, 51.9552059550143], [4.15444398971689, 51.9552128237138], [4.15444044886959, 51.9552177200663], [4.15443865168087, 51.9552222418631], [4.15443923881407, 51.9552268588818], [4.15444092135565, 51.9552307785263], [4.15444298610341, 51.9552339735687], [4.15444629104812, 51.9552370192111], [4.15445534161554, 51.9552443870051], [4.15446483986256, 51.955251362268], [4.15448382433094, 51.9552652336594], [4.15448776829233, 51.9552677746563], [4.15449318432327, 51.9552709060702], [4.15450241092217, 51.9552754863636], [4.15452300497942, 51.955285329965], [4.15453824031121, 51.9552937062619], [4.15454245175035, 51.9552960788814], [4.15454561861781, 51.9552979445711], [4.15456594774732, 51.9553099339055], [4.15459229357712, 51.9553254296351], [4.15464191525211, 51.9553546507727], [4.15465231101248, 51.955360764169], [4.15465859595601, 51.9553644621118], [4.15466637536171, 51.9553688406826], [4.1546799158694, 51.9553764618104], [4.15470881581473, 51.9553927282534], [4.15475404800551, 51.9554181747056], [4.1547931604236, 51.9554402475427], [4.15483933442796, 51.9554663249045], [4.15489803181424, 51.955499426732], [4.15497391816807, 51.9555419479254], [4.15502816797944, 51.9555722269093], [4.15521185779678, 51.9556748113414], [4.15521854878699, 51.9556786012916], [4.15523215875562, 51.9556862867257], [4.15525968048007, 51.9557017924267], [4.15531587588816, 51.9557334128084], [4.15539605485017, 51.9557784871227], [4.15545223648729, 51.9558100985153], [4.15550006968955, 51.9558372244548], [4.1555821117283, 51.9558839289923], [4.1556531656099, 51.9559243581457], [4.15571084150208, 51.9559571898981], [4.15575467873497, 51.9559825116192], [4.15577142100565, 51.9559922971065], [4.15586776058515, 51.9560487130445], [4.15597459510793, 51.9561112739416], [4.15607050744831, 51.9561678739727], [4.156186850707, 51.9562365474323], [4.15625057443824, 51.9562742484043], [4.15626187199972, 51.9562809109672], [4.15628826274479, 51.9562968830076], [4.15632145423021, 51.9563169247915], [4.15636617873384, 51.9563439827195], [4.15642074754836, 51.9563770756733], [4.15650248472579, 51.9564264186668], [4.15658143808182, 51.9564739175338], [4.1566438164413, 51.9565113518298], [4.1566922283403, 51.956540355326], [4.156778882477, 51.9565924094312], [4.15690072488315, 51.9566643833289], [4.15700810691238, 51.9567278092786], [4.15718981280395, 51.9568350728362], [4.15730382759268, 51.9569022526224], [4.15734199718392, 51.9569243432631], [4.15741715327021, 51.956967629904], [4.15746748279997, 51.9569966882408], [4.1575376815596, 51.9570372082406], [4.15760891173135, 51.9570782042376], [4.15767118074012, 51.9571139864916], [4.15773178373545, 51.9571488668695], [4.15784777688943, 51.9572155927656], [4.15795141408409, 51.9572756450859], [4.15797448499047, 51.9572890143525], [4.15798801960911, 51.9572968917982], [4.15802649040363, 51.9573191631231], [4.15810207082085, 51.957362956316], [4.15816275297215, 51.9573980831064], [4.15825053768702, 51.9574489255554], [4.15835516236254, 51.9575095365179], [4.15844323089497, 51.9575594995537], [4.15845622611299, 51.9575668446079], [4.15852066066687, 51.9576032415923], [4.15859247060844, 51.9576438853406], [4.15876112459255, 51.9577403026461], [4.15877613658007, 51.9577489811038], [4.15892230425588, 51.9578330007905], [4.15903879897745, 51.9579000884794], [4.15918357108278, 51.9579836082499], [4.15939555765273, 51.9581059871677], [4.15943085311475, 51.9581263484958], [4.15944936725607, 51.9581372558363], [4.15948040557335, 51.9581557292382], [4.15952474457179, 51.9581820818471], [4.15960062489039, 51.9582272246924], [4.15963001771722, 51.9582446933055], [4.15968830287712, 51.9582793597379], [4.1597152385024, 51.9582952379291], [4.15983920323583, 51.9583681394627], [4.15995701275586, 51.9584373884531], [4.15997852224748, 51.9584499641396], [4.16013406378908, 51.9585402732638], [4.16015771223152, 51.9585540036494], [4.16019874570785, 51.9585778569682], [4.16024615823486, 51.9586057688079], [4.16026463620498, 51.9586169741047], [4.1602930486459, 51.9586340702093], [4.16034535374609, 51.9586655839174], [4.16042163371764, 51.958711630173], [4.1604981843536, 51.9587577867365], [4.16055171249858, 51.9587903116516], [4.16069098416305, 51.9588750033104], [4.16076788146936, 51.9589218831379], [4.1609616496925, 51.9590405007312], [4.16099047467305, 51.9590581188896], [4.16100495629455, 51.9590668683353], [4.16102767658478, 51.9590805252198], [4.16105785218062, 51.9590986380611], [4.16107911282384, 51.9591113733462], [4.16112380322928, 51.9591381942529], [4.16115259283852, 51.9591554213624], [4.16118309973376, 51.9591737636684], [4.16121711219552, 51.9591942076314], [4.16126249008364, 51.9592214855441], [4.16129849341028, 51.9592426547034], [4.16134746764856, 51.9592714448432], [4.16136909074776, 51.9592841816577], [4.1613997662567, 51.9593022096405], [4.1614439158778, 51.9593281645012], [4.16148273935781, 51.9593509145798], [4.16151773697121, 51.9593715859864], [4.16153148030151, 51.9593798009662], [4.16156361418994, 51.9593991937844], [4.16158577541764, 51.9594125221249], [4.1616440097752, 51.9594479880583], [4.16166775723903, 51.9594624192409], [4.16170521315513, 51.9594851747441], [4.16175556522312, 51.959515822532], [4.16180053632117, 51.9595430608782], [4.16181176426386, 51.9595497309503], [4.16183389343816, 51.9595630676869], [4.1618900536954, 51.9595968395971], [4.16193677755531, 51.9596249410731], [4.16199283515873, 51.9596587052794], [4.16202840649307, 51.9596801089196], [4.16205854065712, 51.9596983373783], [4.16207707028074, 51.959708724333], [4.16209311364412, 51.9597179266353], [4.16211072285921, 51.9597289777393], [4.16213154748822, 51.9597427419438], [4.16213748693795, 51.9597458674777], [4.16214219282059, 51.9597477248493], [4.16215451824752, 51.9597519330035], [4.16216476805993, 51.9597538371498], [4.16218052690674, 51.959753292444], [4.16219509859102, 51.959748868482], [4.16220738204127, 51.9597429020192], [4.16222749685703, 51.9597298341947], [4.16223999818647, 51.9597238239114], [4.16225249753222, 51.959719578066], [4.16227057894959, 51.9597165842233], [4.16228831464075, 51.959717146421], [4.16229965958577, 51.9597199244404], [4.16231197081278, 51.959725824468], [4.16232313574379, 51.9597346774626], [4.16232945171892, 51.959746394385], [4.16232958782177, 51.9597579372133], [4.16232432632285, 51.9597737032985], [4.16231060710909, 51.9597992153052], [4.16230576874284, 51.9598106712095], [4.1623046706305, 51.9598237022907], [4.16230836134075, 51.9598350319565], [4.16231246970592, 51.9598423827699], [4.1623189489983, 51.9598507195123], [4.16232515505409, 51.959856312351], [4.16233404368608, 51.9598622754863], [4.16234617821419, 51.9598676228246], [4.16236333930747, 51.9598732309993], [4.16237999301355, 51.9598760840513], [4.16237735852126, 51.9598756440289], [4.16237398479259, 51.9598750865775]]]
            },
            "properties": {
                "SE_FLD1_BEDRIJFSSTATUS": "In bedrijf",
                "SE_FLD24_NETSCHAKELID": "WL-MVL380 W",
                "SE_FLD25_OBJECTID": "32364",
                "SE_FLD27_OBJECTTYPE": "HSkabeldeel",
                "SE_FLD31_SPANNINGSNIVEAU": 380,
                "SE_FLD4_BOUWJAAR": "Sat, 01 Jan 2005 00:00:00 GMT",
                "ESRI_OID": 2933
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries/methods to do this.  Look at https://terraformer-js.github.io/wkt-parser/ for example.

Comment: I gather from your response there is no way to achieve this in SQL?